# How to generate and run a single contract test without building all the unit and contract tests in the project? Java Spring Cloud Contract Verifier

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, testing, spring-cloud-contract

I'm new to contract testing. To run tests I use maven command `mvn clean test`. It runs all the tests in my project, spring cloud generates contract test classes and whole process takes a lot of time. When developing tests I want to check it quickly (generate and run). I wonder if there is any way to run only one test. For unit tests it is simple - just press green triangle against the method/class. But in my case contract tests are generated from groovy + java base test class. So I can't just press the green button.
I tried using junit annotation `@Category`, it partially helps. I put the annotation on one BaseTestClass hoping it gonna build only current class. Instead it builds all the contract tests. It saves a little time, but not so much. And I have to run tests manually by going to targer folder.
Also I tried `@Tag`, it is a bit more convenient because it not only builds but also runs tests.

Answer (score 0):

You can press the green button. Just ensure that the generated tests are there on the classpath in your ide. Even without that, you can run `mvn test -Dtest="NameOfYourClass#nameOfYourTest"` to run a single test with Maven.

To speed things up, in order to both generate the tests and run a single one you can run `mvn org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin:generateTests test -Dtest="NameOfYourGeneratedTestClass#nameOfYourGeneratedTest"`

Comment: I can press the green button when tests are already generated. I'm curious how to do it before generating. `"NameOfYourClass#nameOfYourTest"` - I can't do it in `BaseTestClass` because it only contains @BeforeEach setup() and different mockSomething() methods

Comment: You won't do it on the baseclass but on the generated test. You can't run a test if it's not generated. I think I don't understand the requirement anymore. You can only run a test if it got generated.

Comment: The requirement is to generate & run a single test with minimum repeated manual actions and with minimum time. Now I use `@Tag("MyTest")` on baseclass and run `mvn clean test -Dgroups="MyTest"`. Still not very fast

Comment: I've edited the answer where I show you how to generate tests and run a single test. I double checked it in my projects and it works fine. You can use the maven daemon to speed things even further https://github.com/apache/maven-mvnd

Comment: I got an error: "Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test: No tests were executed". Surprisingly, because I don't use surefire anymore

Answer (score 0):

The solution I've come up with so far is using **Tag**.

1. Add plugin to **pom**:

   ```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <groups>MyTest</groups>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
   ```
2. Add `@Tag("MyTest")` on **BaseTestClass**. It can be any other string instead of "MyTest", just don't forget to change it in all the places.
3. Call **maven command**: `mvn clean test -Dgroups="MyTest"`.

Result: it saves a little time. Now it gonna work only with contract tests, not unit tests. All test classes are generated (unfortunately not only chosen BaseTestClass). Then, only chosen test class is launched automatically.